# rectangles with and wihout border in one graph

Tags: graph, border, gnuplot

How can I plot rectangles with a border and other rectangles without a border in one graph? I couldn't find a solution. But this idea might be a workaround: plotting some rectangles with borders with colour white.

Answer (score 4):

A white border becomes visible when the rectangle is drawn in front of an other object.

Add `noborder` to the set object command:

```
set obj rect from 1, 1 to 3, 3 fc lt 1 fillstyle pattern 4 
set obj rect from 2, 2 to 4, 4 fc lt 2 fillstyle pattern 5 noborder
```

[image]